# Sysytem Out of Memory exception

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am developing vb.net app and all is working great except that i got out of memory Exception `an error Occurred while processing this command . EXCEPTION OF TYPE 'System Out of Memory exception' was thrown`  on the design view when i try to configure or change the properties of controls such as `Datagridview`, `toolstrip`,`statusstrip'`

Comment: You need to tell more about your exception. First thing you need to take in action is to increase runtime attribute `<httpRuntime targetFramework="yourframework" executionTimeout="1999999999" maxRequestLength="1999999999" />`

Comment: Please provide more information. As it stands this is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an easy fix, you just need to restart Visual Studio.